# Is there a way to connect my YOLO v3 model to my webcam?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, yolo

I'm following this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/shahkaran76/yolo_v3-tensorflow-ipynb/blob/master/YOLO%20Tensorflow.ipynb) on yolo_v3 using TensorFlow. The code runs smoothly on single images (images I'm loading from my computer), but I'm trying to connect the model to my webcam.

I tried to look into [OpenCV tutorial on capturing a video from camera](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), but I can't figure out how to combine that with the statement that starts a TensorFlow session to run my model:

```
batch_size = len(img_names)
batch = load_images(img_names, model_size=_MODEL_SIZE)


class_names = load_class_names('files/coco.names')
n_classes = len(class_names)
max_output_size = 10
iou_threshold = 0.5
confidence_threshold = 0.5

tf.reset_default_graph()


model = Yolo_v3(n_classes=n_classes, model_size=_MODEL_SIZE,
            max_output_size=max_output_size,
            iou_threshold=iou_threshold,
            confidence_threshold=confidence_threshold)

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 416, 416, 3]) #I think 
that the batch size will be 1 since we're dealing with 1 frame at a time

detections = model(inputs, training=False)
model_vars = tf.global_variables(scope='yolo_v3_model')
assign_ops = load_weights(model_vars, 'files/yolov3.weights')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(assign_ops)
    detection_result = sess.run(detections, feed_dict={inputs: batch})

draw_boxes(img_names, detection_result, class_names, _MODEL_SIZE)
```

**EDIT:**
I have tried to run:

```
def generator():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3,416)
    cap.set(4,416)

    time.sleep(10)

    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        yield frame


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(assign_ops)
    for frame in generator():
        detection_result = sess.run(detections, feed_dict={inputs: np.expand_dims(frame, 0)})
        draw_boxes(img_names, detection_result, class_names, _MODEL_SIZE)
```

But I'm either getting an error that says that the image was not loaded properly (empty frame), or this:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 240, 320, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(1, 416, 416, 3)'
```

**EDIT 2**
I feel like it's almost working. I ran

```
def generator():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (416, 416))
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        yield frame
    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(assign_ops)
    for frame in generator():
        detection_result = sess.run(detections, feed_dict={inputs: np.expand_dims(frame, 0)})
        draw_boxes(frame, detection_result, class_names, _MODEL_SIZE)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I tried to run the code without the last part:

```
draw_boxes(frame, detection_result, class_names, _MODEL_SIZE)
```

and my camera does in fact turn on, though without any object detection (the YOLO model)

This is the `draw_boxes` function by the way:

```
def draw_boxes(img_names, boxes_dicts, class_names, model_size):
    """Draws detected boxes.

    Args:
        img_names: A list of input images names.
        boxes_dict: A class-to-boxes dictionary.
        class_names: A class names list.
        model_size: The input size of the model.

    Returns:
        None.
    """
    for num, img_name, boxes_dict in zip(range(len(img_names)), img_names,
                                         boxes_dicts):
        img = Image.open(img_name)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font='files/futur.ttf',
                                  size=(img.size[0] + img.size[1]) // 100)
        resize_factor = \
            (img.size[0] / model_size[0], img.size[1] / model_size[1])
        for cls in range(len(class_names)):
            boxes = boxes_dict[cls]
            if np.size(boxes) != 0:
                color = np.random.permutation([np.random.randint(256), 255, 0])
                for box in boxes:
                    xy, confidence = box[:4], box[4] #xy – Top left corner of the text.
                    xy = [xy[i] * resize_factor[i % 2] for i in range(4)]
                    x0, y0 = xy[0], xy[1]
                    thickness = (img.size[0] + img.size[1]) // 200
                    for t in np.linspace(0, 1, thickness):
                        xy[0], xy[1] = xy[0] + t, xy[1] + t
                        xy[2], xy[3] = xy[2] - t, xy[3] - t
                        draw.rectangle(xy, outline=tuple(color))
                    if class_names[cls] =='car':
                        text = '{} {:.1f}% about {:.1f} cm away'.format(class_names[cls], #text – Text to be drawn.
                                                   confidence * 100,
                                                  Distance_To_Obect(4.3,121,780,xy[3]-xy[1],3.5).distance()) 
                    elif class_names[cls] =='person':
                        width, height = img.size
                        print(width, height)
                        text = '{} {:.1f}% about {:.1f} cm away'.format(class_names[cls], #text – Text to be drawn.
                                                   confidence * 100,
                                                  Distance_To_Obect(4.3,170,height,xy[3]-xy[1],3.5).distance()) 

                    else:
                        text = '{} {:.1f}%'.format(class_names[cls], #text – Text to be drawn.
                                                   confidence * 100)
                    text_size = draw.textsize(text, font=font)

                    print ('[x0, y0, x1, y1]', xy[0], xy[1] ,xy[2], xy[3])

                    draw.rectangle(
                        [x0, y0 - text_size[1], x0 + text_size[0], y0],
                        fill=tuple(color)) #fill – Color to use for the text
                    draw.text((x0, y0 - text_size[1]), text, fill='black',
                              font=font)

        display(img)
```

I tried to replace the

```
img = Image.open(img_name)
```

with

```
Image.fromarray(img_name)
```

But I got an error (after running the file again):

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Also, I have ran

```
print (detection_result)
```

And it does contain points

**EDIT 3**
I tried changing the `draw_boxes` method to the one in [this link](https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/blob/master/Convert/yad2k/yad2k/utils/draw_boxes.py)
But I got this error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fa46870a1059> in <module>
    105         detection_result = sess.run(detections, feed_dict={inputs: np.expand_dims(frame, 0)})
    106         print(detection_result)
--> 107         draw_boxes(frame, detection_result, class_names, _MODEL_SIZE)

<ipython-input-5-fa46870a1059> in draw_boxes(image, boxes, box_classes, class_names, scores)
     36     font = ImageFont.truetype(
     37         font='font/FiraMono-Medium.otf',
---> 38         size=np.floor(3e-2 * image.size[1] + 0.5).astype('int32'))
     39     thickness = (image.size[0] + image.size[1]) // 300
     40

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in truetype(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    278
    279     try:
--> 280         return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    281     except IOError:
    282         ttf_filename = os.path.basename(font)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in __init__(self, font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    143         if isPath(font):
    144             self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding,
--> 145                                      layout_engine=layout_engine)
    146         else:
    147             self.font_bytes = font.read()

OSError: cannot open resource
```

**EDIT 4**
This is the `result_box` by the way:

```
[{0: array([[131.96371   , 131.70601   , 341.41946   , 358.6781    ,
          0.68467134]], dtype=float32), 1: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 2: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 3: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 4: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 5: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 6: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 7: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 8: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 9: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 10: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 11: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 12: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 13: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 14: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 15: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 16: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 17: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 18: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 19: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 20: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 21: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 22: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 23: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 24: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 25: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 26: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 27: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 28: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 29: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 30: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 31: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 32: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 33: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 34: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 35: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 36: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 37: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 38: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 39: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 40: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 41: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 42: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 43: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 44: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 45: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 46: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 47: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 48: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 49: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 50: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 51: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 52: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 53: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 54: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 55: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 56: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 57: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 58: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 59: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 60: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 61: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 62: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 63: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 64: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 65: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 66: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 67: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 68: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 69: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 70: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 71: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 72: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 73: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 74: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 75: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 76: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 77: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 78: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32), 79: array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=float32)}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the link you provided the frame is the image you need to feed to yolo. You could place the whole while true from the link into the session and just process frame by frame by running:

```
detection_result = sess.run(detections, feed_dict={inputs: np.expand_dims(frame, 0)})
```

or write a generator that provides the frames, kind of cleaner.

```
def generator()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (416, 416))
        yield frame
```

and then in your could do:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(assign_ops)
    for frame in generator():
        detection_result = sess.run(detections, feed_dict={inputs: np.expand_dims(frame, 0)})
```

The expand dims is to create a batch of 1, so eg: makes 399x399x3 into 1x399x399x3.

Something like that, hope it helps a bit

EDIT

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def convert_bbox_to_absolute(bbox_list, w_img, h_img):
    """
    method to convert the relative points (< 1) to absolute points (< 416)
    :param bbox_list: (list) list of boundary boxes (x, y, w, h, probability)
    :param w_img: (int) width of the image
    :param h_img: (int) height of the image
    :return: bbox_list: (list) list of boundary boxes but this time scaled up
    """
    x, y, w, h, c = zip(*bbox_list)
    y = list(map(lambda y: int(y * w_img), y))
    w = list(map(lambda w: int(w * h_img), w))

    x = list(map(lambda x: int(x * h_img), x))
    h = list(map(lambda h: int(h * w_img), h))
    bbox_list = zip(x, y, w, h, c)
    return list(bbox_list)


def draw_boxes(image, bbox_list):
    """
    Will draw the rectangles on th image and place the probability on them
    :param image:  (np.ndarray) a RGB-color image
    :param bbox_list: (list) list of boundary boxes (x, y, w, h, probability)
    """
    assert type(image) == np.ndarray
    assert type(bbox_list) == list

    assert len(image.shape) == 3
    assert len(bbox_list[0]) == 5

    # get the width and height of the image
    w_img, h_img, _ = image.shape

    # convert the box coordinates to absolute values
    bbox_list = convert_bbox_to_absolute(bbox_list, w_img, h_img)
    for bbox in bbox_list:
        x, y, w, h, c = bbox
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(image, str(c), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


# creating a black test RGB-image
test_image = np.zeros((512, 416, 3))

# faking some boundary boxes, x, y, w, h, confidence
b_boxes = [[0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8], [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4]]

draw_boxes(test_image, b_boxes)
```

This is a very simple example of how you can draw boundary boxes, I assumed that the provided boxes by yolo are normalised because of [this link](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-yolo-f5a74bbc7967). If you know how I can determine which label belongs to which box, then I'll add that to the code as well.

EDIT 2:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from random import choices
from string import ascii_lowercase


def draw_boxes(image, bbox_list, label_list):
    """
    Will draw the rectangles on th image and place the probability on them
    :param image:  (np.ndarray) a RGB-color image
    :param bbox_list: (list[dict()]) list dict of boundary boxes  label:(x, y, w, h, probability)
    :param label_list: (list) a list of label names matching the order of the dict keys
    """
    bbox_dict = bbox_list[0]
    assert type(image) == np.ndarray
    assert type(bbox_dict) == dict
    assert type(label_list) == list

    assert len(image.shape) == 3
    assert len(bbox_dict.keys()) == 80
    assert len(label_list) == 80

    for label, bbox in bbox_dict.items():
        if bbox.size == 0:
            continue
        x1, y1, x2, y2, c = np.squeeze(bbox)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = list(map(lambda val: int(val), [x1, y1, x2, y2]))
        label = label_list[label] + ": {}".format(c)

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(image, label, (x1, y1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


# creating a black test RGB-image
test_image = np.zeros((512, 416, 3))

# faking some boundary boxes, x, y, w, h, confidence and auto generating empty arrays with keys, to match your data
b_boxes = [{
    0: np.array([[131.96371, 131.70601, 341.41946, 358.6781, 0.68467134]]),
    1: np.array([])
}]
for i in range(2, 80):
    b_boxes[0][i] = np.array([])

# get 80 random 10 letter strings to mock labels
labels = ["".join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=10)) for _ in range(80)]

draw_boxes(test_image, b_boxes, labels)
```

Given your data, I made some changes, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! It does help a lot! I didn't quite get the last part about the dimensions (please see my edits if you have time)

Comment: I updated the generator code, should work now. Normaly when training you use batches, a batchsize of 10 leads to an array of 10x416x416x3 in your case, it's basically the number of images you feed. The model expects therefore a 4d array. However during testing of the model in real life, it's likely that you want it to process image by image, instead of 10 images simultaneously. A single rgb inage is 3d WxHxC, C is for color channels, a model does not expect it and wants a 4d array, therefore np.expand_dims, this takes in an image and adds a dimension of 1, to the provided axis.

Comment: It does not change your data whatsoever, it just changes the structure a bit, allowing it to be excepted by your model

Comment: You're the best. It does make my camera turn on, though without any model detection (please see my last edits if you have time)

Comment: can you print detection_result, does it contain points, what is the code behind draw_boxes, is it this one? https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/blob/master/Convert/yad2k/yad2k/utils/draw_boxes.py

Comment: I ran detection_results (it does contain points). I updated my edit

Comment: I see what is going wrong, your draw_boxes for some reason does not want an image but a path to an image. The first line calls Image.open on an array, so hence the error from numpy. The code from my link expects an array, try to use that code and tell me if it works

Comment: I tried that but I got an OS error (you can see my edit 3). Again, I really appreciate your time!!!

Comment: Well that is probably just pointing out that it cannot find the font declared in the code. Anyway, I'm going to work now, I'll be back in the evening to write a working variant.

Comment: Sounds good. I am still a bit confused about how come the model works just fine for images but not for my webcam. Let me know if you have any suggestions and I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna start coding your draw boxes in opencv, any Idea how I know which box belongs to a certain label, because just drawing the rectangles might be a bit abstract, and can you give me the value of detection_result

Comment: I'm not sure about how we're matching a box to a label, though it looks like we're passing a 'boxes_dict' which is a class-to-boxes dictionary. And then we're matching each box with the dictionary in the 'boxes = boxes_dict[cls]' . Again, I'm not really sure. I've been staring at this for a couple of hours now. Please see my edit for the values of the detection_result. I did try the draw_box method you wrote and it seems like its missing 2 arguments (since the other draw_box is: 'def draw_boxes(img_names, boxes_dicts, class_names, model_size):')

Comment: Yea, I know it is missing 2 arguments, because I don't really know what to do with them, but I'll go on my laptop, trying to make sense of the  data. Os it trained to recognize 79 different objects?

Comment: Oh, I see. I believe it is trained to recognize 80 different objects. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, so I will soon modify my method to take in your dict, and a list of label names, then the method is finished

Comment: Awesome! Looks like it's almost working. I'm getting an error that relates to CV2 but I think that something that relates to my machine. Still troubleshooting it.

Comment: Well if you need help with it open a new question and let me know :)

Comment: Hi! I did have another question in regard to the model. I don't know if you're interested or have time, but I'd appreciate any help : ) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421366/how-do-i-make-the-bounding-boxes-in-yolo-v3-tighter-closer-to-the-objects)