# How do I make the bounding boxes in yolo v3 tighter (closer to the objects)?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, object-detection, bounding-box, yolo

I'm following this [Repo](https://github.com/ayooshkathuria/YOLO_v3_tutorial_from_scratch) on creating Yolo v3 model from scratch in PyTorch. The only problem is that the bounding boxes are not as tight (close to the objects) in most images I tried. I compared them to the [tutorial](https://github.com/shahkaran76/yolo_v3-tensorflow-ipynb/blob/master/YOLO%20Tensorflow.ipynb) on creating Yolo v3 model but using TensorFlow. The tensorflow model produces excellent bounding boxed that are as tight as possible to the objects.
I tried to understand how the calculations are different between the two, but I'm finding myself getting stuck with the differences between torch and tf.
I believe the code for the bounding boxes in the tf tutorial comes from here:

```
def yolo_layer(inputs, n_classes, anchors, img_size, data_format):
    """Creates Yolo final detection layer.

    Detects boxes with respect to anchors.

    Args:
        inputs: Tensor input.
        n_classes: Number of labels.
        anchors: A list of anchor sizes.
        img_size: The input size of the model.
        data_format: The input format.

    Returns:
        Tensor output.
    """
    n_anchors = len(anchors)

    inputs = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, filters=n_anchors * (5 + n_classes),
                              kernel_size=1, strides=1, use_bias=True,
                              data_format=data_format)

    shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
    grid_shape = shape[2:4] if data_format == 'channels_first' else shape[1:3]
    if data_format == 'channels_first':
        inputs = tf.transpose(inputs, [0, 2, 3, 1])
    inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, n_anchors * grid_shape[0] * grid_shape[1],
                                 5 + n_classes])

    strides = (img_size[0] // grid_shape[0], img_size[1] // grid_shape[1])

    box_centers, box_shapes, confidence, classes = \
        tf.split(inputs, [2, 2, 1, n_classes], axis=-1)

    x = tf.range(grid_shape[0], dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.range(grid_shape[1], dtype=tf.float32)
    x_offset, y_offset = tf.meshgrid(x, y)
    x_offset = tf.reshape(x_offset, (-1, 1))
    y_offset = tf.reshape(y_offset, (-1, 1))
    x_y_offset = tf.concat([x_offset, y_offset], axis=-1)
    x_y_offset = tf.tile(x_y_offset, [1, n_anchors])
    x_y_offset = tf.reshape(x_y_offset, [1, -1, 2])
    box_centers = tf.nn.sigmoid(box_centers)
    box_centers = (box_centers + x_y_offset) * strides

    anchors = tf.tile(anchors, [grid_shape[0] * grid_shape[1], 1])
    box_shapes = tf.exp(box_shapes) * tf.to_float(anchors)

    confidence = tf.nn.sigmoid(confidence)

    classes = tf.nn.sigmoid(classes)

    inputs = tf.concat([box_centers, box_shapes,
                        confidence, classes], axis=-1)

    return inputs
```

While the code for the bounding boxes for the pytorch model comes from [here](https://github.com/ayooshkathuria/YOLO_v3_tutorial_from_scratch/blob/master/util.py), and the [explanation](https://blog.paperspace.com/how-to-implement-a-yolo-v3-object-detector-from-scratch-in-pytorch-part-3/):

```
def bbox_iou(box1, box2):
    """
    Returns the IoU of two bounding boxes 


    """
    #Get the coordinates of bounding boxes
    b1_x1, b1_y1, b1_x2, b1_y2 = box1[:,0], box1[:,1], box1[:,2], box1[:,3]
    b2_x1, b2_y1, b2_x2, b2_y2 = box2[:,0], box2[:,1], box2[:,2], box2[:,3]

    #get the corrdinates of the intersection rectangle
    inter_rect_x1 =  torch.max(b1_x1, b2_x1)
    inter_rect_y1 =  torch.max(b1_y1, b2_y1)
    inter_rect_x2 =  torch.min(b1_x2, b2_x2)
    inter_rect_y2 =  torch.min(b1_y2, b2_y2)

    #Intersection area
    inter_area = torch.clamp(inter_rect_x2 - inter_rect_x1 + 1, min=0) * torch.clamp(inter_rect_y2 - inter_rect_y1 + 1, min=0)

    #Union Area
    b1_area = (b1_x2 - b1_x1 + 1)*(b1_y2 - b1_y1 + 1)
    b2_area = (b2_x2 - b2_x1 + 1)*(b2_y2 - b2_y1 + 1)

    iou = inter_area / (b1_area + b2_area - inter_area)

    return iou

def predict_transform(prediction, inp_dim, anchors, num_classes, CUDA = True):


    batch_size = prediction.size(0)
    stride =  inp_dim // prediction.size(2)
    grid_size = inp_dim // stride
    bbox_attrs = 5 + num_classes
    num_anchors = len(anchors)

    prediction = prediction.view(batch_size, bbox_attrs*num_anchors, grid_size*grid_size)
    prediction = prediction.transpose(1,2).contiguous()
    prediction = prediction.view(batch_size, grid_size*grid_size*num_anchors, bbox_attrs)
    anchors = [(a[0]/stride, a[1]/stride) for a in anchors]

    #Sigmoid the  centre_X, centre_Y. and object confidencce
    prediction[:,:,0] = torch.sigmoid(prediction[:,:,0])
    prediction[:,:,1] = torch.sigmoid(prediction[:,:,1])
    prediction[:,:,4] = torch.sigmoid(prediction[:,:,4])

    #Add the center offsets
    grid = np.arange(grid_size)
    a,b = np.meshgrid(grid, grid)

    x_offset = torch.FloatTensor(a).view(-1,1)
    y_offset = torch.FloatTensor(b).view(-1,1)

    if CUDA:
        x_offset = x_offset.cuda()
        y_offset = y_offset.cuda()

    x_y_offset = torch.cat((x_offset, y_offset), 1).repeat(1,num_anchors).view(-1,2).unsqueeze(0)

    prediction[:,:,:2] += x_y_offset

    #log space transform height and the width
    anchors = torch.FloatTensor(anchors)

    if CUDA:
        anchors = anchors.cuda()

    anchors = anchors.repeat(grid_size*grid_size, 1).unsqueeze(0)
    prediction[:,:,2:4] = torch.exp(prediction[:,:,2:4])*anchors

    prediction[:,:,5: 5 + num_classes] = torch.sigmoid((prediction[:,:, 5 : 5 + num_classes]))

    prediction[:,:,:4] *= stride

    return prediction
```

Comment: I alos need the answer for this one. What I can tell is you can apply fix weighting on the union area to impose higher IoU on large bounding box. For example you can multiply the Union area times 5 before calculating IoU criterion. But I think your questions is towards postprocessingt after you have the bounding box rather than the training step itself to tighten your bounding box area?

Comment: also looking for possible ways to get box as tight as possible.